# Backbone fetch() throws an Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ajax' of undefined

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript, undefined, fetch, typeerror

I am integrating BackBone on a new project. While I am somewhat familiar with BackBone, this will be my first attempt at creating a new project with it.

I setup a model and view, but am getting a console error that doesn't return any helfpul results on StackOverflow or Google. I'm hoping someone here can spot where I've gone wrong.

Here's the error, which occurs when I call `thing.fetch()`

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ajax' of undefined
```

And here's my CoffeeScript code:

```
Thing = Backbone.Model.extend
    name: 'thing'
    url: ->
        "/things/#{@id}"

ThingView = Backbone.Model.extend
    el: "#thing"
    render: ->
        console.log 'render', @$el

thing = new Thing(id: 1)
thing.fetch()

thingView = new ThingView()(model: Thing)
thingView.render()
```

Comment: it depends on jQuery or zepto. Is one of those included in your page?

Comment: `new ThingView()(model: Thing)` that's a typo, right?

Comment: user1737909: No, that is not a typo. What did you see wrong there?

explunit: I'm using jQuery 1.10.0, Underscore 1.4.4, and Backbone 1.0.0

Comment: Where are you using ajax? Should be used somewhere as it is complaining about var or object.

Comment: @ricardohdz Backbone uses $.ajax behind the scenes, thus my earlier comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

UPDATE: Solved this on my own. Rookie mistake, not loading dependancies first. I realized that I had goofed and loaded Backbone before jQuery instead of after jQuery. The ajax method was an undefined property because jQuery didn't exist at that point in my code.

A lot of times the simple solution is the correct one. Thank you everyone who jumped in to help out!

Answer (score 2):

As explunit mentioned in the comments, it looks like you are seeing that error because you are attempting to call $.ajax (via fetch) but $ is undefined (ie, jQuery is not loaded correctly).

If you post some more information, I can try and give more insight/details about how to fix the issue.

A few other notes that I wanted to make...

- `ThingView = Backbone.Model.extend` should be `ThingView = Backbone.View.extend` (view not a model)
- In coffeescript I would write `class Thing extends Backbone.Model` instead of `Thing = Backbone.Model.extend` and the same for ThingView
- I am also confused by your syntax here `new ThingView()(model: Thing)` seems like a double paren typo, but maybe I am forgetting something here

You shouldn't need it here since this seems to be simply a jQuery issue, but you may have luck debugging future issues with backbone apps using [backbone.debug](http://andrewterris.com/backbone.debug/) (disclaimer: I created this)

Comment: Sorry, you were write about the typo. That line of code was copypasta from a tutorial blog.

Comment: I want to give you an upvote for the additional tips, but being a new user, I don't have the reputation yet. Thank you regardless!

Answer (score 0):

I screwed up by using jQuery.slim, you dont want jquery.slim[.min].js